# Overriding the default error message for a ModelForm

Tags: django-forms

Is there any way to override a error_message text for all the fields of a ModelForm's, without having to include all the field info in the ModelForm?

For example, let's say I have a (very simple) model like this:

```
People(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Please type your name.")
     age = models.IntegerField(help_text="Please type your age.")
```

I don't like the cut and dry default messages, such as, "Enter a whole number.", so I'd like to change them to something a bit nicer like "Please type a number." Ideally I'd be able to add an "error_message" property in the model, but the model does not support that property. So does that mean I have to basically duplicate all the model info in my ModelForm, or is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [use this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960795/django-how-to-cleanup-form-fields-and-avoid-code-duplication/2961987#2961987) to create functions for validation based on django native functions and your error messages )) .

Comment: Looks very interesting. Thank you for taking the time to respond.